# animate opacity of radial gradient without css3

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, radial-gradients

I have a radials gradient and I want animate the opacity to make transparent and then restore the real opacity...

I searched the posibles solutions such as

```
context.globalAlpha
```

but all radials gradient remain invisible and I want one...

other possible solutions?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code of what you did?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mexB3/ is a sample...when the circle is animated ... I want animate the opacity in the transition

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

You can use `context.globalAlpha` to change the opacity of a radial gradient:

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Cd79L/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color:white; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    // variables used to draw & animate the ring
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var cancelAnimationId;
    var startingX=100;
    var endingX=225;
    var x=startingX;
    var deltaX=1;
    var y=100;
    var radius=50;

    // start the animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // the animation loop
    function animate() {

        // request another animation loop
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // create the gradient at the current x,y
        var radgrad=ctx.createRadialGradient(x,y,0,x,y,radius);
        radgrad.addColorStop(0.00,"green");
        radgrad.addColorStop(1.00,"white");
        ctx.fillStyle=radgrad;

        // draw the ring at the radius set using the easing functions
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalAlpha=(x-startingX)/100;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,PI2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

        x+=deltaX;
        if(x<startingX || x>endingX){deltaX*=-1;x+=deltaX;}
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to add a `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` to combat his issue of everything after this draw call being drawn invisible

Comment: Thanks @Jnatalzia! I left off the ctx.restore. :-)